# How to equalize participants volume on Google Meet?

Tags: audio, google-meet

When attending calls on Google Meet, I often meet the issue where participants have very different mic volumes.

This is annoying as it's hard to hear the persons with lower audio volume without increasing the output volume on my computer, but then the sound will be too loud for the persones with louder microphones.

Is there a way to equalize the participants volumes or will I have to play with my volume controls forever?

Comment: There used to be some amount of this built into Google Meet, but in the past few weeks / months it seems like it's been disabled. Did you come across any solution to this?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. I'm still looking for a solution.